# Celery in a microservice architecture

Tags: python, docker-compose, celery, microservices

I am currently working on a microservices architecture on my project and all my services app1, app2, ... are using celery and celery beat.

Is it possible to link all my apps to one celery instance? If yes could you give me a docker-compose example? Or should I create a celery instance for every app or service I have in my project?

Comment: From what we have, every service has its own celery instance. Since it is not safe when you could maybe send a task to the same queue from different services which will be processed by the wrong worker.
Maybe if it is a pet project we are working with Camunda/Zeebe cloud microservice orchestrator/workflow engine and it is very cool :D, maybe it is your wanted solution.

Comment: thanks, so i should create for every service its celery worker, isnt there any tool that can handle many celery instances at once?, also ill take a look on those technologies

Comment: For management of multiple celery instance I found another stack overflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747174/running-multiple-celery-instances-in-production-in-same-vm-different-virtual-env
Unfortunately I have no experience with that and I would say yes, you have to have multiple instances of celery

Comment: I believe that's the case, each instance is managing the tasks of one app, also you need to specify its own queue to avoid conflicts. another solution is to make a mixed worker with multiple queues, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of celery is managing the tasks of one app, also it is needed to specify its own queue to avoid conflicts. Another solution is to make a mixed worker with multiple queues if many needed in a single app.

```
worker:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
command: ['celery', '--app=app.celery', 'worker', '--loglevel=INFO', 
           '--queues=monitor']
environment:
  - BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:pass@rabbitmq:5672//
  - RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
  - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
volumes:
  - /app/:/app/
depends_on:
  - rabbitmq
  - redis
```